# Find duplicates from two columns in a table based on another column in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I have a table to store phone numbers

phone_numbers

```
--------------------------------
id | primary | phone1 | phone2  |
--------------------------------
1  | phone1  |  xxx   |  xxx    |
2  | phone2  |  xxx   |  xxx    | 
3  | phone2  |  xxx   |  xxx    | 
4  | phone1  |  xxx   |  xxx    |
5  | phone2  |  xxx   |  xxx    |
6  | phone1  |  xxx   |  xxx    |
```

How do I find duplicate entries (and corresponding records) for primary phone number from the table? If primary is phone1, the value is stored in phone1 and if primary is phone2, value is stored in phone2 field

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find duplicate entries (and corresponding records) for primary phone number from the table?

If you want to display the entire original records, the simplest option probably is `exists` and conditional expressions:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1
    where 
        case when t1.primary = 'phone1' then t1.phone1 else t1.phone2 end
            = case when t.primary = 'phone1' then t.phone1 else t.phone2 end
        and t1.id <> t.id
)
```

In MySQL 8.0, an alternative uses a window count:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        count(*) over(partition by case when primary = 'phone1' then phone1 else phone2 end) as cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data model and store the phones on separate *rows*.  Absent that, you can unpivot and aggregate to find numbers in different columns:
The following returns all phones that appear more than once and the columns where the phone is stored:

```
select phone, sum(is_primary) as num_primary, sum(is_1) as num_1, num(is_2) asnum2
from ((select primary as phone, 1 as is_primary, 0 as is_1, 0 as is_2
       from phone_numbers pn
      ) union all
      (select phone1, 0 as is_primary, 1 as is_1, 0 as is_2
       from phone_numbers pn
      ) union all
      (select phon2, 0 as is_primary, 0 as is_1, 1 as is_2
       from phone_numbers pn
      ) 
     ) t
where phone is not null
group by phone
having count(*) > 1;
```